# Python tkinter maintaining gui and reading from pipe

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to achieve reading from subprocess pipe stdout and stderr and updating GUI simultaneously. However my code is waiting all pipe reading process then updates all.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
import subprocess
import threading
import time
from queue import *

class Application:
    
    # load main window of application
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.current_script_file_name = None
        self.q = Queue()

        self.window = master
        self.window.title("TK")
        self.window.rowconfigure(1, minsize = 600, weight = 2)
        self.window.columnconfigure(1, minsize = 600, weight= 2)

        # create frame for buttons and create buttons
        self.frame_buttons = tk.Frame(master = self.window, relief = tk.RAISED, bd = 2)
        self.button_save = tk.Button(master = self.frame_buttons, text = "Save", command = self.save_script_to_file)
        self.button_run = tk.Button(master = self.frame_buttons, text = "Run", command = self.run_script_from_file)

        # create frame for tk.Text editor and output
        self.frame_text = tk.Frame(master = self.window, relief = tk.RAISED, bd = 2)
        self.text_editor = tk.Text(self.frame_text)
        self.text_output = tk.Text(self.frame_text, background = "Black", foreground = "White")

        #adjust buttons
        self.button_save.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.button_run.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 5)
        self.frame_buttons.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "ns")

        #adjust text editor and text output
        self.text_editor.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.text_output.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.frame_text.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "ns")

        self.text_output.insert(tk.END, 'Script Result:\n')
        
    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

    def save_script_to_file(self):
        file_path = asksaveasfilename(
            filetypes=[("Python Scripts", "*.py"), ("Kotlin Scripts", "*.kts*")]
        )
        if not file_path:
            return
        with open(file_path, "w") as output_file:
            text = self.text_editor.get(1.0, tk.END)
            output_file.write("#!/usr/bin/env python3\n")
            output_file.write(text)
            
        self.window.title(f"Text Editor Application - {file_path}")


    def run_script_from_file(self):
        # start thread so main window not going to freeze
        threading.Thread(target=self.run_script).start()
        self.update()



    def run_script(self):
        sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','script.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        threading.Thread(target=self.pipe_reader, args=[sub_proc.stdout]).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.pipe_reader, args=[sub_proc.stderr]).start()

    def update(self):
        while not self.q.empty():
            for source, line in iter(self.q.get, None):
                self.text_output.insert(tk.END,line)
        self.window.after(1000,self.update)


    def pipe_reader(self, pipe):
        try:
            with pipe:
                for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):
                    self.q.put((pipe, line))
        finally:
            self.q.put(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    app.run()
```

run_script_from_file is a button command. And self.q is a Queue belongs to same class of this functions.

Why my text_output tk.Text field is not updating asap

Script.py :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time

counter = 1
while counter < 6:
    print ("The current counter value: %d" % counter)
    counter = counter + 1
    time.sleep(1)


print(asd)
```

Edit: I put all my code
Edit: Added script.py

Comment: This isn't enough code for us to give a certain answer, but I'll guess it's because you left out the `flush=True` from the other script, which is causing the output to be buffered. Why are you doing this via subprocess in the first place rather than just `import script`?

Comment: It is almost all the code i wrote actually. I kinda trying to implement something like CMake. In GUI,it creates a subprocess and runs script and shows output on another field.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] before we can give specific help. It should include the other program if that is also something you wrote. I don't understand your cmake comment. If you are trying to run another python program in parallel you don't need subprocess, you can simply import the other file and run the import in another thread or process or as part of a tkinter mainloop (depending on what it does).

Comment: That CMake example was bad. I want to run a script from another language and see output simultaneously while script executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is actually not too far off. One common gotcha, due to buffering you have to run python in `-u` mode. Only other thing really is to have the tkinter update loop running all the time. Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
import subprocess
import threading
import time
from queue import *

class Application:

    # load main window of application
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.current_script_file_name = None
        self.q = Queue()

        self.window = master
        self.window.title("TK")
        self.window.rowconfigure(1, minsize = 600, weight = 2)
        self.window.columnconfigure(1, minsize = 600, weight= 2)

        # create frame for buttons and create buttons
        self.frame_buttons = tk.Frame(master = self.window, relief = tk.RAISED, bd = 2)
        self.button_save = tk.Button(master = self.frame_buttons, text = "Save", command = self.save_script_to_file)
        self.button_run = tk.Button(master = self.frame_buttons, text = "Run", command = self.run_script_from_file)

        # create frame for tk.Text editor and output
        self.frame_text = tk.Frame(master = self.window, relief = tk.RAISED, bd = 2)
        self.text_editor = tk.Text(self.frame_text)
        self.text_output = tk.Text(self.frame_text, background = "Black", foreground = "White")

        #adjust buttons
        self.button_save.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.button_run.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 5)
        self.frame_buttons.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "ns")

        #adjust text editor and text output
        self.text_editor.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.text_output.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew", padx = 5, pady = 5)
        self.frame_text.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "ns")

        self.text_output.insert(tk.END, 'Script Result:\n')

        self.update()

    def save_script_to_file(self):
        file_path = asksaveasfilename(
            filetypes=[("Python Scripts", "*.py"), ("Kotlin Scripts", "*.kts*")]
        )
        if not file_path:
            return
        with open(file_path, "w") as output_file:
            text = self.text_editor.get(1.0, tk.END)
            output_file.write("#!/usr/bin/env python3\n")
            output_file.write(text)

        self.window.title(f"Text Editor Application - {file_path}")

    def run_script_from_file(self):
        sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-u','script.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        threading.Thread(target=self.pipe_reader, args=[sub_proc.stdout]).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.pipe_reader, args=[sub_proc.stderr]).start()

    def update(self):
        while not self.q.empty():
            source, line = self.q.get()
            if line is None:
                line = "DONE"
            self.text_output.insert(tk.END,line)
        self.window.after(100, self.update)

    def pipe_reader(self, pipe):
        for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):
            self.q.put((pipe, line))
        self.q.put((pipe, None))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Can you explain why did you delete app.run and changed update function?

Comment: Just because they aren't needed.